# expected primary expression before } in C++

Tags: c++, label, do-while, goto

Why a label can not be placed immediately before `}while(/*exp*/);` in a do-while loop, instead of expecting a primary expression.

```
int main()
{
    
    int x = 5;
    
    do{
        if(x==2) goto label;
        
        printf("%d", x);
label:
        ; // if not error: expected primary-expression before ‘}’ token
    }while(--x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rules of C++ (as well as C, by the way), you cannot leave the parentheses of an `if` empty either... Has nothing to do with the loop, by the way, it is the colon after the label that requires a primary expression *following*!

Comment: [Labeled_statements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Labeled_statements)

Comment: Get rid of the goto and label and replace this line `if(x==2) goto label;` with `if(x==2) continue;`

Comment: @drescherjm In *this* case – absolutely. Sometimes we still need it (e.g. for exiting from nested loops: `if(something) { for(...) { for(...) { goto DONE; } } DONE: ; }`)...

Comment: @Aconcagua, of course, it is the use case; exit from nested loops. Thank you, everybody, now I understand it.

Comment: Refactoring can often help you out here, by leaving a situation where you can use `return` instead of `goto`

Comment: @Aconcagua I had some doubts combining `goto` with nested loops. To my surprise, even with `goto` the scopes (and proper destruction of local instances) are handled properly. [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c2c4556d0d09b8f) -> `goto` doesn't seem to be that evil as I was thinking...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Well, it indeed is not. It's a useful tool that *can* help to write clean code – but also to do bad things as well. Always the same: It's not the tool's fault if being used for where it shouldn't. I can use an axe to chop wood, but I can kill people with as well. Is it now the axe that is bad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Labels may be placed before statements. The symbol `'}'` does not denote a statement.

So you need to include a null statement after the label and before the closing brace.

```
label:
        ;
    }while(--x);
```

Pay attention to that it is better to rewrite the do while statement without the goto statement like

```
do{
    if ( x != 2 ) printf("%d", x);
}while(--x);
```

Also bear in mind that opposite to C in C++ declarations are also statements. So you may place a label before a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that labels are to label a statement. In other words, you can't have a label without a statement following. and the semicolon is equivalent to an empty statement but } doesn't denote a statement.

```
label: /* semicolon for empty statement*/ ;
```